# Why is there no implicit conversion from int to string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, int, implicit-conversion

For example, an int with a value of 10 would always be converted to "10", no? Is it not possible to define such conversion yourself?

EDIT: what I'm asking for is:

```
int i = 10;
Blah(i);

public void Blah(string param)
{
...
}
```

Comment: There are many ways of representing an int as a string. "10" and "0xA" are only two of them...

Comment: @Fredrik my english teacher prefered "Ten", this question is not constructive. Just use `ToString()` or, some overload there of.

Comment: The best explanation I have found: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333427/why-cant-c-implicitly-convert-int-to-string for a good explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# is a strongly typed language. Conversions like the one you are asking about [are not implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx). Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx

Comment: Some are. Anything concatenated with a string is implicitly converted to a string, via `ToString()`.

Comment: @Rotem. You are correct. I will update

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 10;
s = i.ToString();
```

What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an int to a string using `Int32.ToString()` (either by explicitly calling the method or implicitly by concatenating with another string).

You can then parse the string back to an int using `Int32.Parse()`

Answer (score 1):

when an `int`, or any other `object` must be implicitly converted to a string, `ToString()` is called under the hood.

You can call it explicitly and thus control the conversion, using your own `Culture` object, or a numeric format string.

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

That's because C# has been desgined to be a **strongly typed language**. Strong typing has a series of advantages, mainly related to the fact that the compiler can catch many type related errors that would become runtime errors in a weakly-typed language. You can read more in [Wikipedia: Strong typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing).